# How to convert an IOrderedEnumerable<char> to string in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to sort a string alphabetically. The most common solution I have found is to use linq:

```
var sortedString = unsortedString.OrderBy(c => c);
```

The problem I have with this solution is that the result is not a string. The result is an IOrderedEnumerable< char > which needs to be converted. This does not work:

```
var sortedString = unsortedString.OrderBy(c => c).ToString();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String is a sequence of characters. So

```
unsortedString.OrderBy(c => c)
```

returns sequence of ordered characters as well. I.e. `IEnumerable<char>`. You should create a new instance of string from these ordered characters:

```
var sortedString = new String(unsortedString.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
```

When you use `ToString()` on sequence of characters, you just get a type name of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is `String.Concat` which uses a `StringBuilder`:

```
string sortedString = String.Concat(unsortedString.OrderBy(c => c));
```

or `String.Join` (i prefer `Concat` without a delimiter):

```
string sortedString = String.Join("", unsortedString.OrderBy(c => c));
```